# Adding Google HTML Tag twice?

Tags: html, verification

I'm trying to set up Google Merchant Center for our UK website. It won't let me set it up without the site being verified in search Console. So I logged into SC got it all set-up and verified via a HTML tag. 
Then I logged back into Merchant center and it asked me to do the same. 
Only trouble is, it's asked me to upload a completely different HTML tag code. 
It doesn't seem right to have two Google HTML codes on the same site? Surely that will flag as some sort of error with Google. 
P.S. 
I set-up search console and merchant center using different email addresses, is this the issue? 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but why would you because your website is already searched right?

Comment: To answer 'why would you' We're being asked to verify the site in this way in order to set-up Google Merchant Center. So we kind of have to but it's not ideal. Thanks for your response

Comment: Ok I got it.  Then Yes you can.